# And let who say Amen?

Tags: tefilla, bentching, amen, nuschaot, tzibur-community

In light of [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13826/759), why do we say V'imru amen and V'nomar amen at various points in bentching and davening when saying that passage alone? (eg. bentching by yourself, or oseh shalom at the end of one's silent amida) It sounds like these phrases were instituted for scenarios with group participation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would think that it is better, if possible, to incorporate group participation for these things as much as possible. However, even alone, one says "ואמרו אמן" and the like. Why? I will quote [R' Yaakov Emden](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19725&st=&pgnum=279) (regarding the phrase said at the end of the Amida to conclude "Elokai N'tzor"), but do not assume that I know what he means:

> .ואמרו אמן - אף ביחיד אומרו. כלפי המלאכים המלוים אותו‏
>   *literally:* "And say ye *amen*": even in solitude he says it, toward the angels/messengers who are escorting him.

**EDIT**: I just found [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41247&st=&pgnum=135) P'ri Megadim (EA 189:1) who writes (regarding the conclusion of the Harachaman section in Birkas Hamazon) that when alone, one should not recite "ואמרו אמן" or "ונאמר אמן", but rather just "אמן". [It looks like most siddurim don't follow this, though.]

Comment: Similar idea here in the Rokeach's peirush on tefillah http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49925&st=&pgnum=381&hilite=

Comment: Just to add to this answer.  Once we have a text, it takes a lot of public pressure to change it between when saying it alone or saying it to the group. I'm not aware of any times we do that.

Comment: @DoubleAA that _Rokeach_ is, according to the footnote there, quoting the _Magen Avraham_ 66:27 — which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @msh210 Yes i noticed that. Also, the rokeach lived well before the magen avraham. I assume it's just the footnote guy trying to reference us to someone else who says a similar idea, but failing.

Comment: @DoubleAA, my thoughts exactly — unless the _Rokeach_ really is quoting the _Magen Avraham_ (another book of the same title).

Comment: @msh210 Note that the MA in that siman does mention derech agav that you do say the amen even beyachid. (I saw this when I looked it up last night but don't remember exactly which seif katan). That's a decent coincidence.

Comment: I saw something similar in likutei hapades lerashi that the Malachim cannot understand Aramaic, so we translate  yehei shlama rabba into hebrew for them at the end of kaddish.  On a basic level, we are talking about malachim because of Oseh Shalom "Bimromav".