# Why demand Amen via V'Imru Amen (ואמרוּ אָמֵן) at end of kaddish versus just amen elsewhere?

Tags: kaddish, amen

There are lots of blessings where we say Amen at the end, and even lots of places within kaddish where we say Amen, so why at the end of kaddish must we command others to say Amen by saying V'imru Amen (also said in Bentching)?

Comment: What are some examples of blessings where we say Amen at the end?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13806/759

Comment: @Yehoshua Birkas HaChodesh has Venomar Amein, twice.

Comment: @Ariel Venomar vs Vimru is covered in the linked question. I understood Larry to be asking about places where Amen is said with no prompt, eg. the one 4 words into Kaddish.

Comment: Rokeach seems to address this [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49925&st=&pgnum=82) and [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49925&st=&pgnum=270).

Comment: Huh? *V'imru amein* appears multiple times within *kaddish*.

Comment: @Fred echoes my thoughts. Can you clarify this in your question, I assume that since this phrasing appears after nearly each paragraph, it's an indication that the congregation much join in the response. It makes sense, since Kaddish cannot be said individually. It must be said in a minyan. Can you clarify your question? I'm uncertain of the scope of your concern.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, the prompting of "ואמרו" is not found in all early manuscripts of the *kaddish*, some have "ונאמר".

Dr. de Sola Pool, in his 'The Kaddish' ([pg. 42](https://archive.org/stream/kaddishk00poolrich#page/42/mode/2up)), posits that the idea was to seal closing doxologies as we have elsewhere in the bible where a chapter is ended with the congregation joining in responding "amen" (see ibid. ft. 80). Prior to this prompt the reader of the *kaddish* petitions for the speedy coming of Messiah and kingship of God, a central theme in Judaism. It would follow that the congregation, after being prompted, responds with the "amen" which serves as an expression of affirmation, acceptance and faith (see ibid. ft. 81).